# AWS Quicksight - Get second occurrence

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset as shown below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| User-1 | value 111 |
| User-1 | value 222 |
| User-2 | value 123 |
| User-2 | value 223 |
| User-2 | value 333 |

I am trying to retrieve the second value from Column B grouped by column A.

So for the above dataset, the calculated field should return "value 222" for "User-1" and "value 223" for "User-2".

Is this possible to do with a calculated field? I have tried using various difference/firstvalue functions but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a mix of a calculated field and a filter on your analysis.

You can use the [rank](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/rank-function.html) function to create an ordering of Column B and filter on this calculated field where the rank equals 2

I have tried this with the following for the rank calculated field based off of your example data

```
rank
(
  [ {Column B} ASC ],
  [ {Column A} ] 
)
```